# Using px proxy Windows 10, powershell, cmd, kubectl

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, proxy, git-bash

BACKGROUND: I'm inside a corporate network using win10, I've been instructed to use px proxy and I have to use kubectl to connect to a cluster running in a cloud provider. I have the kubeconfig, in the .kube dir. When I use

`kubectl get no`

I get an error.
If on the otherhand I use Lens and add the proxy localhost:port in the settings it and its terminal work just fine and I can use kubectl as expected. I can describe, apply, top and any other command I'm used to

If I use powershell, cmd, git bash kubectl fails with an error saying it can't reach the cluster the same applys with using curl to the api server.

kubectl is in my path
I don't have admin rights to windows settings. My boss's response is "it works on my machine" and "every new joiner has problems" which is even odder as we're a 2 person team and I joined 4 weeks ago and he's been on holiday for two of them and in a different time zone.

Quetion: Would setting the http_proxy environment variable to the px proxy address enable kubectl, curl and other cli tools to use px proxy?

Comment: As for this ***Quetion: Would setting the http_proxy environment variable to the px proxy address enable kubectl, curl and other cli tools to use px proxy?***; have you tried to set it and make an attempt?

Comment: I'm seeking info prior to trying it as I asked my boss and he said he's never had to do it.I make an environment change on my desktop with out his explicit go ahead he'll report me to legal and HR

Comment: Your boss's environment is obviously different than yours. ***Works on my machine*** is not a meaningful statement, nor useful when it si said to anyone. So, your boss does not use a kubeconfig file either? The PS environment variables are only active when you are in a PS session unless you write them to your System Variable config, and that is not what I was suggesting. Are you saying you cannot go to an isolated environment and use a test system to try this? That's why a test environment exists. I get the HR thing if corp policies/risk postures are restrictive.

Comment: No test environment, he claims to have a kubeconfig but wouldn't send it to me, so accessed our cloud provider through its cli and got the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:
I do not have K8 or even docker. The info I am providing is something that was brought up in a recent meeting I was in.***

As per my comment.

Are you saying, you've set your environment variables, meaning, setting your kubeconfig, file, or something like this...

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    proxy: http://proxy-address:port
```

...as well as:

```
$env:http_proxy = "http://px-proxy-address:port"
```

... at the CLI, or your code, or just add it to your PS profile.

```
Set-Item Env:http_proxy "http://px-proxy-address:port"
Set-Item Env:https_proxy "http://px-proxy-address:port"
Set-Item Env:ftp_proxy "http://px-proxy-address:port"
```

Also, going to virtually any https site(s), requires you set the proper security settings in your code.

Meaning this...

```
# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::
SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::
SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::
Tls12
```

... or this:

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
```

Comment: Thank its the set-item in my ps profile that's really useful

Comment: No worries, and glad it helped.